# Weird behavior in Oracle date columns

Tags: oracle, date, date-conversion

I am getting this weird behavior in Oracle 9i:

```
select
    t.final_day,
    to_char(t.final_day,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') final_day1,
    t.week_first_day,
    to_char(t.week_first_day,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') week_first_day1
from  
    mytable t 
where 
    t.rowid in ( 'AAAJ6QAAZAAACenAAW','AAAJ6QAAZAAACenAAT')
order by 
    t.end_date
```

The weird thing is that dates that were inserted without a time (default to 00:00/12:00 AM) convert OK to chart, but dates that were inserted with a time fail to convert to char:

```
FINAL_DAY               FINAL_DAY1          WEEK_FIRST_DAY          WEEK_FIRST_DAY1 
7/19/2015 12:00:00 AM   19/07/2015 00:00:00 7/13/2015 12:00:00 AM   13/07/2015 00:00:00
7/25/2015 11:00:00 PM   00/00/0000 00:00:00 7/19/2015 11:00:00 PM   00/00/0000 00:00:00
```

- What could be the reason for this and how could I work around it?

**Update:**

This is what I get when I apply the dump function to both date columns:

```
DUMP1                               DUMP2
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,115,7,19,1,1,1    Typ=12 Len=7: 120,115,7,13,1,1,1
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,115,7,26,0,1,1    Typ=12 Len=7: 120,115,7,20,0,1,1
```

**Update2:**

Both columns are of type `DATE`. Behavior persists even after doing `alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`.

Comment: Could it be related to your NLS variables ?

Comment: That's not strictly true, since when you select a date without explicitly converting it into a string, Oracle implicitly converts it to a date via to_char, using the default nls_date_format parameter as the format mask. However, your results with the to_char() are odd; I wouldn't expect to see what you're seeing! What do you get if you add in a `dump(final_day), dump(week_first_day)` into your select statement - could you update your question to add this information in, please?

Comment: Also, what is the datatype of your FINAL_DAY and WEEK_FIRST_DAY columns? And what is the value of your nls_date_format? Does it change anything if you do `alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`

Comment: @Boneist I updated the question.

Comment: what version of 9i? `select version from v$instance;`

Comment: a little bit of research threw up this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/660316. I suspect corrupt date information, as when I compare the dump() results for my date columns, I don't get any 0's in the time elements. eg: `25/03/2015 01:04:30` returns `Typ=12 Len=7: 120,115,3,25,2,5,31`, so it looks like the first number in the list is 1 followed by the first 2digits of the year, next is 1 followed by the last 2 digits of the year, then the month, then the day, then the hour+1, then the minutes+1, then the seconds+1. So, you shouldn't be seeing a 0 in the time element bit, which yours does.

Comment: Similar to [this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12455152/266304), but a different part of the date structure seems to be corrupt, and the NLS_DATE_FORMAT behaviour is different. [And this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7030520/266304). I'd guess everything was supposed to be midnight but there's some time zone/daylight savings confusion in one of the insert mechanisms. Import used to have a bug that did could corrupt like this, I think. How were the rows created?

Comment: @Boneist Could you elaborate into an answer?

Comment: @AlexPoole Could you elaborate into an answer?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova - the questions I linked to before explain this type of problem, not sure a more specific answer here would add much - since it isn't known how the corruption occurred. If you have a similar problem and those answers don't help you, ask a new question with your specific scenario.